# How do i change my plot line style and have two Y-axis for one x-axis?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I took data from excel and plotted it. The first column is date, while the next two columns are prices of different indexes. 
I managed to plot them, but they are on separate graphs. I need them plotted against each other with one y-axis (date) and two x-axis.

Also, I can't figure out how to make the line dotted for one and a diamond marker for the other.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

excel_data = pd.read_excel('Python_assignment_InputData.xlsx', '^GSPTSE')

excel_data.plot(kind='line', x = 'Date', y = 'Bitcoin CAD (BTC-CAD)', color = 'green')
excel_data.plot(kind='line', x = 'Date', y = 'S&P/TSX Composite index (^GSPTSE)', color = 'blue')

plt.show()
```

I expect Bitcoin and S%P prices to be on one y axis, with dates being on the x axis.

Comment: " one y-axis (date) and two x-axis."? Both your x-axis is same. You need 2 y-axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am providing a sample answer using the iris DataFrame from `seaborn`. You can modify it to your needs. What you need is a single x axis and two y-axes.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")

iris.plot(x='sepal_length', y='sepal_width', linestyle=':', ax=ax)
iris.plot(x='petal_length', y='petal_width', marker='d',
          linestyle='None', secondary_y=True, ax=ax)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your help @Bazingaa! I managed to get everything working!

Comment: Thanks @Bazingaa ! It is marked as accepted now. I tried voting, but since I am new, it would not allow me to.